# Easiest way to query nested optional realm objects in swift

Tags: realm

I am using Realm for Swift. I have two Realm objects structures like this:

```
class outerObject : Object {
   dynamic var innerObject : innerInfo?
}

class innerInfo : Object {
  dynamic var sortId = 5
}
```

I want to make a query that gets every outerObject where the innerInfo is not nil and sortId equals 3.
Normally I would use something like:

```
realm.objects(outerObject).filter(predicate)
```

And then write a suitable NSPredicate but I do not hink that works with optionals. So what is the recommended method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query should work: `realm.objects(outerObject).filter("innerObject.sortId = 3")`.

Answer (score -2):

when innerObjc is nil, this will been broken. Expected object of type string for property '' on object of type '', but received: (null),the 2nd anwser is not the right anwser.

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question